# How to find HTML rendered by <?php wp_head(); ?> in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have done a lot of search on it, most of the people are saying

wp_head() is located in wp-includes/general-template.php

wp_head is in default-filter.php in wp-includes

But I want to know where the html/php file placed in file directory that is rendered by wp_head(), so I can edit that file. Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `wp_head()` function simply calls all functions hooked to the `wp_head` action. Various functions will be hooked to this action, they may reside in the WordPress core, or perhaps in plugins you may be using, or even in your theme's functions.php file.

To my knowledge, there isn't a specific wp_head template 'file' that you can edit.

Ref:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head

Comment: I think the better question would be what does do_action( 'wp_head' ); do... the two links offer absolutely no information

Comment: New links: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/ , https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/

Answer (score 4):

Following https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head

> wp_head() is located in wp-includes/general-template.php.

If you want edit something, execute a Control+MAJ+F (Find in folder) in wp-includes and it gives you the file where the specific content should be edited.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_head()` is located in `wp-includes/general-template.php`.