# Can't find where/how WordPress scripts are imported wp_head();

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hi all I have some trouble with a Wordpress website.

I'm changing the way the scripts are loaded on the website (async vs sync) and doing some purge to useless scripts (multiple versions of jquery etc. etc.).
Some of them were loaded plain and simple on the header (**header.php**) and i have moved them already, some of the others are loaded with a function called **wp_head();**

This function loads a lot of stuff (scripts and plain text javascript) but i can't find where it is...

i read there
[How to find HTML rendered by <?php wp_head(); ?> in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454624/how-to-find-html-rendered-by-php-wp-head-in-wordpress)
that there are many function hooked to this one by, for instace, plugins and more but how it is possible to find them all?

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Usually scripts are hooked in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook that is hooked in `wp_head`. 
*I mean usually because not every developer follows the guidelines.*

You can check the functions hooked in `wp_enqueue_scripts` using this functions, that [@Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) created

Put this in your functions.php:

```
/**
 * A function to visually dump a hook.
 *
 * @param $tag
 * @param $hook
 */
function cis_dump_hook($tag, $hook) {
    ksort($hook->callbacks);

    echo "<pre>>>>>>\t$tag<br>";

    foreach ($hook->callbacks as $priority => $functions) {

        echo $priority;

        foreach ($functions as $function) {
            if ($function['function'] != 'list_hook_details') {

                echo "\t";

                if(is_closure($function['function'])) {
                    echo "Closure: function(){}";
                } else if (is_string($function['function'])) {
                    echo $function['function'];
                } else if (is_string($function['function'][0])) {
                    echo $function['function'][0] . ' -> ' . $function['function'][1];
                } else if (is_object($function['function'][0])) {
                    echo "(object) " . get_class($function['function'][0]) . ' -> ' . $function['function'][1];
                } else {
                    print_r($function);
                }
                echo ' (' . $function['accepted_args'] . ') <br/>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}

function list_hooks( $filter = false ){
    global $wp_filter;

    $hooks = $wp_filter;
    ksort( $hooks );

    foreach( $hooks as $tag => $hook )
        if ( false === $filter || false !== strpos( $tag, $filter ) )
            dump_hook($tag, $hook);
}
```

and call it like this: `list_hooks( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' );`

I really recommend to do this in a development environment.
This will return a list of functions hooked in the **`wp_enqueue_scripts`** hook.
To know more about the functions check the post [Debug WordPress hooks](http://www.rarst.net/wordpress/debug-wordpress-hooks/).

Comment: Do not worry for the english as it's not my native language too.
Thank you very much for your time and advice, i will try as soon as possible and i will let you know.

Thank you again!